# Problem with multiple inline <script>'s with parameters that output filtered json

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm fairly new at js and trying to make a centralised glossary inside a restricted education environment (LMS) with no database or anything that would make this easier. I need to make a script hosted on our app server that can be embedded in a dozen or so courses and a learning designer requirement is that there can be two or more on the same page. The terms and definitions are in **glossary.json** and look something like this:

```
{
    "a": [
        {
            "module": "1.1",
            "term": "A term in module 1.1",
            "definition": "<p>A definition in 1.1</p>"
        }, {
            "module": "1.2",
            "term": "A term in module 1.2",
            "definition": "<p>A definition in 1.2</p>"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'm trying to do is have the relevant terms for a section of the course embedded inline with a query parameter as follows:

```
<h2>Module 1.1</h2>
<p>Course content about module 1.1 goes here</p>    
<script src="glossary.js?m=1.1"></script>
    
<h2>Module 1.2</h2>
<p>Course content about module 1.2 goes here</p>  
<script src="glossary.js?m=1.2"></script>
```

**glossary.js** creates a div with an id named after the m parameter and should only output relevant terms like so:

```
function ajax_get(url, callback) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
        try {
            var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err.message + " in " + xmlhttp.responseText);
                return;
            }
            callback(data);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

var script = document.currentScript;
var queryString = script.src.replace(/^[^\?]+\??/,'');
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
var module = urlParams.get('m');

var el = document.createElement("div");
el.setAttribute("id", "glossary"+module);
document.body.appendChild(el);
 
ajax_get('glossary.json', function(data) {
    var html = "<dl>";
    for (var i=0; i < data["a"].length; i++) {
        if (data["a"][i]["module"] == module) {
            html += '<dt>' + data["a"][i]["term"] + '</dt>';
            html += '<dd>' + data["a"][i]["definition"] + '</dd>';
        }
    }
    html += "</dl>";
    el.innerHTML = html;
});
```

However, in the example above even though the script is "called" twice and will create the two div's it will only populate the last one like so:

```
<h2>Module 1.1</h2>
<p>Course content about module 1.1 goes here</p>   
<script src="ajax.js?m=1.1"></script>
<div id="glossary1.1"></div>

<h2>Module 1.2</h2>
<p>Course content about module 1.2 goes here</p>  
<script src="ajax.js?m=1.2"></script>
<div id="glossary1.2">
    <dl>
        <dt>A term in module 1.2</dt>
        <dd><p>A definition in 1.2</p></dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

I simply can't get it working. How come each script is happy to be self-contained until the JSON is called. I've tried two different ways of retrieving the JSON contents but produce the same undesired result. I have a feeling it might be something simple but any tips for what's causing it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi , you are calling that script on click of something ? Please elaborate more

Comment: heya, no click event, the script is supposed to just load up the glossary terms when the page is viewed

Comment: But you are not having any loop to iterate through `scripts` tag and get parameter from that script only ? Above js code will call your function only 1 time ..? How you are looping through all scripts ?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. I was hoping if the script was embedded in HTML on the page twice then it would run twice.

Answer (score 0):

You are not looping through your `script` tags from where you need to get `src` so to overcome this one way is to use some `loop` that will iterate through the `script` tag and depending on this execute your function .Changes you can make in your current code :

```
   //get all script tag with src="glossary"
    var scripts = document.querySelectorAll("script[src*='glossary']");
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
     if (scripts[i].src) 
    //get parameter
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(scripts[i].src.replace(/^[^\?]+\??/, ''));
    var module = urlParams.get('m');
     var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.setAttribute("id", "glossary" + module);
    scripts[i].parentNode.insertBefore(el, scripts[i].nextSibling);
    data_();//call some function to do further process
    }
```

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//your data
var data = {
  "a": [{
    "module": "1.1",
    "term": "A term in module 1.1",
    "definition": "<p>A definition in 1.1</p>"
  }, {
    "module": "1.2",
    "term": "A term in module 1.2",
    "definition": "<p>A definition in 1.2</p>"
  }]
}

//get script tag with src="glossary"
var scripts = document.querySelectorAll("script[src*='glossary']");
//loop through it
for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
  if (scripts[i].src)
  //get param
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(scripts[i].src.replace(/^[^\?]+\??/, ''));
  var module = urlParams.get('m');
  var el = document.createElement("div");
  el.setAttribute("id", "glossary" + module);
  //insert newly created div after script tag
  scripts[i].parentNode.insertBefore(el, scripts[i].nextSibling);
  data_();//call your function
}

function data_() {
  var html = "<dl>";
  for (var i = 0; i < data["a"].length; i++) {
    if (data["a"][i]["module"] == module) {
      html += '<dt>' + data["a"][i]["term"] + '</dt>';
      html += '<dd>' + data["a"][i]["definition"] + '</dd>';
    }
  }
  html += "</dl>";
  el.innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<h2>Module 1.1</h2>
<p>Course content about module 1.1 goes here</p>
<script src="glossary.js?m=1.1"></script>

<h2>Module 1.2</h2>
<p>Course content about module 1.2 goes here</p>
<script src="glossary.js?m=1.2"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for giving it a go, but for some reason i'm getting different results to the code snippet. an exact copy/paste of your example outputs two <div id="glossary1.1"> and when i substitute the glossary data for a JSON file i'm back to the original problem of it only populating the second <div>

Comment: can you create jsfiddle of your code ? Also , you don't need to call your ajax multiple times just call only one time and use the return data to populate your divs .